# Printing Carmichael numbers in a given limit

Tags: python, number-theory

I'm trying to list all of the Carmichael numbers under 10000, however, I think I have issue with the `print_carmichael` function. For some reason, it does not print all of the `n` values when the  `is_carmichael` is true.

```
  def is_carmichael(n): 
      b = 2
      while b<n:
          if (gcd(b, n) == 1):
              if (pow(b, n - 1, n) != 1): 
                  return 0
          b = b + 1
      return 1

  def print_carmichael(max):
      for n in range(2, max):
          if is_carmichael(n):
              print(n)
      return 0
```

Comment: It prints a lot of numbers (actually a bit too many, including non-carmichael numbers) for me. What do you expect to see?

Comment: calling `print_carmichael(1000)` for me causes max recursion depth reached.

Comment: Yes, that's the issue. I'd like to output only carmichael numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary issue I see is that you're not filtering out prime numbers as [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CarmichaelNumber.html) notes:

> A Carmichael number is an odd composite number

```
from math import gcd

def is_prime(number):
    if number <= 2:
        return number == 2

    if number % 2 == 0:
        return False

    for divisor in range(3, int(number ** 0.5) + 1, 2):
        if number % divisor == 0:
            return False

    return True

def is_carmichael(n):

    # a Carmichael number is an odd composite number
    if n <= 2 or n % 2 == 0 or is_prime(n):
        return False

    for a in range(3, n, 2):
        if gcd(a, n) == 1:
            if pow(a, n - 1, n) != 1:
                return False

    return True

def print_carmichael(maximum):
    for number in range(maximum):
        if is_carmichael(number):
            print(number)

print_carmichael(100_000)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
% python3 test.py
561
1105
1729
2465
2821
6601
8911
10585
15841
29341
41041
46657
52633
62745
63973
75361
%
```

There's probably a more efficient way to do the *composite* test but you get the idea.  We can *simplify* this code, at a cost of *speed*, by using the logic in `is_charmichael()` itself to filter out primes and tossing our explicit `is_prime()` function:

```
def is_carmichael(n):

    # a Carmichael number is an odd number
    if n <= 2 or n % 2 == 0:
        return False

    may_be_prime = True

    for a in range(3, n, 2):
        if gcd(a, n) == 1:
            if pow(a, n - 1, n) != 1:
                return False
        else:
            may_be_prime = False

    return not may_be_prime
```